# TI Simplelink CC3200SF FreeRTOS HC-SR04 Ultrasonic sensor distance reading

Tags: c, freertos

I am very new to FreeRTOS and am trying to use a HC-SR04 Ultrasonic sensor and TI-Simplelink CC3200SF Board to try to get distance readings.  I understand that you need to initialize the Trigger GPIO in order to trigger the sensor and then wait and read a response from the Echo GPIO and calculate the distance from the time.  However, I am confused on how to use the timer or measure time within FreeRTOS.  After I've initialized the pins and set the trigger pin to high I'm not sure how to read the time between the trigger pin deactivating and the Echo pin.

I've read through most of the syntax for the timers in FreeRTOS but it's not really making sense.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be useful to add snippets of the code you tried